# changing beginning of items in list of figures and tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

{
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables%
}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
 \caption{just a table}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
 u & m
  \end{tabular}
   
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [<->,thick] (-0.6,-1)to(-0.6,-2) ;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An arrow}

\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I've got some good LOF and LOT but must change it like below with colon

Figure 1.1 ---> **Figure 1.1 :**

Table 1.1 ---> **Table 1.1 :**

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading package `tocloft`, so you can use it to get the desired prefixes in LOF and LOT:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries\figurename~}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{:}
\setlength\cftfignumwidth{5.5em}

\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\bfseries\tablename~}
\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{:}
\setlength\cfttabnumwidth{5em}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\caption{just a table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
u & m
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->,thick] (-0.6,-1)to(-0.6,-2) ;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An arrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]